# How is "X with tilde on top" pronounced when spoken?

Tags: notation, pronunciation

How is $\tilde{X}$ pronounced when a paper is being read out loud?

Sorry if this is a duplicate but couldn't figure out how to search for it. TIA

Comment: I have heard both "X tilde" and "X squiggle" be used. Often the "on top" part is implicit.

Comment: All my preofessors have sad "X tilde" :)

Comment: I hear it as "X twiddle".

Comment: It is properly *$X$ tilde*, just as Spanish *ñ* is *n tilde*.